# Форматирование данных в инпут. Маска для инпута рубли и копейки.(Vue directive)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vue.js, input, inputmask

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто делал подобное.

Нужно реализовать директиву для инпута. Смысл ее такой:
Например: Ввод с клавиатуры "5" - отображается "0.05". Ввод с клавиатуры "1005" - отображается "10.05". Две последние введенные цифры отделяются от предыдущих точкой.

Какую регулярку добавить вместо этой **replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')**?

```
    Vue.directive('format', {
  bind(el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: VNode) {
    const { modifiers } = binding;
    const targetElement = el;

    if (modifiers.cost) {
      targetElement.addEventListener('input', (e: any) => {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
      });
    }
  },
  update(el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: VNode) {
    const { modifiers } = binding;
    const targetElement = el;

    if (modifiers.cost) {
      targetElement.addEventListener('input', (e: any) => {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: `.replace(/\B(?=\d{2}$)/, '.')`? Или `replace(/\d{2}$/, '.$&')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew второй вариант, уже очень классно, спасибо! Но есть  минус : 
1) при вводе одной цифры, не получается 0.05, в инпуте просто 5
2)даже если ввести две цифры например 15, то в инпуте не 0.15, а вот так: **.15**

Comment: `x.replace(/\B\d{2}$/,'.$&').replace(/^\d$/,'0.0$&').replace(/^\d{2}$/,'0.$&')`? Или ``x.replace(/(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, (m,n,o) => m.length == 3 ? `${n}.${o}` : m.length == 2 ? `0.${m}` : `0.0${m}` )``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
x.replace(/\B\d{2}$/,'.$&').replace(/^\d{2}$/,'0.$&').replace(/^\d$/,'0.0$&')
```

Ещё один вариант:

```js
x.replace(/(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, (m,n,o) => m.length == 3 ? `${n}.${o}` : m.length == 2 ? `0.${m}` : `0.0${m}`)
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\B` - позиция в строке, отличная от границы слова (тут между двух цифр)
- `\d{2}` - две цифры
- `(\d{0,2})` - Захватывающая подмаска: ноль, одна или две цифры
- `$` - конец строки.

`$&` ссылается на значение целого совпадения. В `(m,n,o)` `m` означает целое совпадение, `n` – первая подмаска, `o` — вторая подмаска.

См. пример на JavaScript:

```js
const arr = ['1', '12', '123'];
// Вариант №1
arr.forEach(x => console.log(x, '=>', x.replace(/\B\d{2}$/,'.$&').replace(/^\d$/,'0.0$&').replace(/^\d{2}$/,'0.$&')))
// Вариант №2
arr.forEach(x => console.log(x, '=>', x.replace(/(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, (m,n,o) => m.length == 3 ? `${n}.${o}` : m.length == 2 ? `0.${m}` : `0.0${m}` )))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Вы случайно не в курсе, как можно поправить баг при вводе в инпут.
Там значение по умолчанию  стоит 0.00 и если с клавиатуры ввести 5, то получается 00.05
если далее вводить например 6, то получается 000.56
Ну и например дописать еще две цифры с клавиатуры в инпут 13, то в инпуте отображается 00056.13.
Я понимаю, что маска вызывается при вводе каждого символа , отсюда и баг наверное, но как поправить не пойму.

Comment: @NickolayKapitanov Если поделитесь кодом (http://jsfiddle.net для этого подходит), то, может, помогу.

Comment: написал коротенький пример: https://jsfiddle.net/qd5ge1tp/

Comment: @NickolayKapitanov Вы не удаляете начальные нули, а надо. `this.value = e.target.value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9]/g, '')` - https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/tnLxk7a2/

Comment: Thank you, master :)

Comment: Я тут недавно, плюсик это стрелочка вверх, что  ответ полезен?

Comment: Да, это голос "за". Спасибо.